# Flutter- using Route in weight calculator

Tags: android, flutter, dart, routes

route setting in flutter app is not working when run on real-time it's not working and did not give any output

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    initialRoute: 'front_end',
    routes: {'login': (context) => MyLogin()},
  ));
}
```

[image]

route setting in the flutter app is not working when run in real-time it's not working and did not give any output.

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'front_end.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    initialRoute: 'front_end',
    routes: {'login': (context) => MyLogin()},
  ));
}

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `initialRoute` on `routes`

```dart
  initialRoute: 'front_end',
  routes: {
    'login': (context) => MyLogin(),
    'front_end': (context) => HomeWidget(), //this
  },
```

It would be better to use `/` for home widget.

More about [`navigation`](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation)